# Confirmar envio Sweet Alert Laravel

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

Estoy tratando de eliminar un registro con doble confirmación de sweet alert desde un datatables, pero al seleccionar uno, siempre me envia el id 1, sin importar que sea el registro con el id 10, 20 o 30. A que se debe o que estoy haciendo mal?. Anexo codigo qu genera el listado

```
@foreach ($array as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/users/'.$row->login.'/image.png') }}" style="max-width:30px;">
            {{ $row->firstName.' '.$row->lastName }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $row->email }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $row->login }}
        </td>
        <td>

            <!-- Action buttons -->
            <div>
                {!! Form::open(array('route' => array($options['route'].'.destroy', $row->id), 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'myform'.$row->id)) !!}


                    <a href="{{ route($options['route'].'.show', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"> 
                        <i class="la la-small la-edit"></i> 
                    </a>

                    <button type="button" id="delete" data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-small la-trash"></i></button>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

y la función js que genera el Sweet alert

```
$('button#delete').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        swal({
          title: "¿Desea eliminar el usuario?",
          text: "",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Si!!",
          cancelButtonText: "No!!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {

            swal({
                title:'¡El usuario será eliminado!',
                text: '',
                type: 'success'
            }, 
            function() {
              $("#myform"+id).submit();
            });

          } else {

            swal("Cancelled", "El usuario no será eliminado!!", "error");

          }
        });

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas repitiendo la misma id y eso no se debe hacer, recuerda que la id debe ser única, trabaja con clases para eso, **.delete** te sería más útil

Cambia esto

```
<button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-small la-trash"></i></button>
```

por esto

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"><i class="la la-small la-trash"></i></button>


$('.delete').on('click', function() {

        swal({
          title: "¿Desea eliminar el usuario?",
          text: "",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Si!!",
          cancelButtonText: "No!!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {

            swal({
                title:'¡El usuario será eliminado!',
                text: '',
                type: 'success'
            }, 
            function() {
              $("#myform").submit();
            });

          } else {

            swal("Cancelled", "El usuario no será eliminado!!", "error");

          }
        });

    })
```

recuerda que también te puedes apoyar en los data atributos para agregar por ejemplo la id para identificar el botón donde se haya hecho clic, lo digo por el hecho de intentar identificar el formulario que vas a enviar.

Cambia esto también déjalo así:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array($options['route'].'.destroy', $row->id), 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'myform'.$row->id)) !!}
```

a tu botón colocale este data atributo:

```
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="la la-small la-trash"></i></button>
```

y tu switalert así:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        swal({
          title: "¿Desea eliminar el usuario?",
          text: "",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Si!!",
          cancelButtonText: "No!!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {

            swal({
                title:'¡El usuario será eliminado!',
                text: '',
                type: 'success'
            }, 
            function() {
              $("#myform"+id).submit();
            });

          } else {

            swal("Cancelled", "El usuario no será eliminado!!", "error");

          }
        });

    })
```

de esa manera identifica a que formulario enviar al momento de darle clic a un botón

Comment: Gracias por responder. Sigo con el mismo problema, si lo djo con el `type="button"`, evia el formulario y sigue capturando el primer id, asi trate de enviar el id 30, sin embargo, si lo dejo `type="submit"`, envia sin pasar por la validacion del sweet alert.

Comment: @ErainMoya actualiza tu código arriba para revisar, pero te aseguro que no hiciste bien ,los cambios, de haberlos hecho correctamente te estaría enviando el formulario correcto y no todos, lo que digo es que si te esta enviando el primer id es porque no cambiaste nada, pues si el monitoreo es a una clase como te dije y capturas el id desde un data atributo no da problemas, es algo que hago casi que a diario en mis sistemas, actualiza el codigo y vemos que hiciste o no hiciste

Comment: Listo, actualizado.

Comment: @ErainMoya veo que dejaste esta linea igual, `$('button#delete').on('click', function() {` asi no te va a funcionar y como te comente, deja de repetir la id **delete** pues las ids no se pueden repetir, lee bien mi respuesta e interpreta bien los cambios y veras que si te funciona. Saludos

Comment: Si la había cambiado, solo que no la había cambiado acá. Igual ya solucione con tu respuesta. Mil gracias, ya que detalles como esos son lo que te quitan un buen tiempo.